# A way to handle async state updates on Redux store without using redux-thunk or redux-saga middleware?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga, redux-thunk

**I'm all in favor of NOT solving problems you don't have.**

So I started learning and using React without Redux.

But now **my app state has grown** and I'm starting to face some **state management issues**.

It's getting hard to handle it and my `App.js` is full of `<SomeContext.Provider's>`.

So I'm **willing to add Redux to my app now**.

But of course I'm making lots of **API calls to get data for my App state**. So, from my research basically I have **two major options for async state updates:** `redux-thunk` and `redux-saga`.

Both of them add cumbersome boilerplate and new concepts to handle and maintain.

**But my question is: do I really need them (thunk or saga)?**

I made this code that seems to work and it updates the store with async data.

**The result:**

[image]

https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-antonelli-9cu7m

**The code:**

Basically I have this reducer:

**getApiDataReducer.js**

```
const initialState = {
  loading: false,
  error: null,
  data: null
};

function getApiDataReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "GET_DATA_START":
      return {
        ...initialState,
        loading: true
      };
    case "GET_DATA_SUCCESS":
      return {
        ...initialState,
        loading: false,
        data: action.payload
      };
    case "GET_DATA_FAIL":
      return {
        ...initialState,
        loading: false,
        error: action.payload
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default getApiDataReducer;
```

**rootReducer.js**

```
import getApiDataReducer from "./getApiDataReducer";
import { combineReducers } from "redux";

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  getApiData: getApiDataReducer
});

export default rootReducer;
```

**And I have my index.js file with my App component:**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { createStore } from "redux";
import { Provider, useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import rootReducer from "./reducers/rootReducer";

import "./styles.css";

const store = createStore(rootReducer);

function mockAPIcall() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve("DATA FROM API"), 1000);
  });
}

function mockAPIcallError() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => reject("SOMETHING WRONG HAPPENED"), 1000);
  });
}

function App() {
  const { loading, error, data } = useSelector(state => state.getApiData);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  async function getAsyncData() {
    dispatch({ type: "GET_DATA_START" });
    try {
      const newData = await mockAPIcall();
      dispatch({ type: "GET_DATA_SUCCESS", payload: newData });
    } catch (err) {
      dispatch({ type: "GET_DATA_FAIL", payload: err });
    }
  }

  async function getAsyncDataError() {
    dispatch({ type: "GET_DATA_START" });
    try {
      const newData = await mockAPIcallError();
      dispatch({ type: "GET_DATA_SUCCESS", payload: newData });
    } catch (err) {
      dispatch({ type: "GET_DATA_FAIL", payload: err });
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        Data:
        {
          loading ? "Loading..."
          : error ? error
          : data ? data
          : "No data yet..."
        }
      </div>
      <button onClick={getAsyncData}>Get Async Data</button>
      <button onClick={getAsyncDataError}>Get Async Error</button>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  rootElement
);
```

---

**QUESTION:**

I'm pretty sure those libraries (`redux-thunk` and `redux-saga`) can do much more than that. So **I want to know which key features of those libraries am I losing** by adopting this much simpler pattern.

Because from what I did on my app so far, I could pretty much refactor everything to this pattern. But I'm pretty sure I'm closing some future doors by doing it this way.

It seems like an open ended question, but I don't think it is. **People use those libraries and they should be able to tell which important features are not being taken into consideration while using this pattern.**

Comment: Are you sure redux-thunk requires lots of boilerplate?  redux-thunk only requires 2 lines of code, first is importing it, and the second is `const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));`

Comment: You're right. The boiler plate isn't the issue. But `redux-thunk` has its own way of doing things that you have to learn. And `redux-saga` is even more complex. I think I'm not ready for them yet, since I never had the problems that they solve. I'm just looking for a way to benefit from redux as a single central state manager. I need basic async updates for my app and I don't want to commit to `thunks` or `sagas`. At least, not yet. Thanks!

Comment: I think best option for you is using redux-thunk, it is very simple.

Comment: We [officially recommend using thunks for standard async work](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#use-thunks-for-async-logic), and [our new Redux toolkit package automatically adds thunks to the store setup by default](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Redux in a purely synchronous way (shielding it from any asynchronicity which Redux doesn't support anyway) and are missing benefits afforded by the [Separation of Concerns](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22redux-saga%22+%22separation+of+concerns%22) design principle.

**EDIT BY OP:** This article has helped me a lot: [Separation of concerns design principle in Redux using redux-saga](https://medium.com/@ywongcode/separation-of-concerns-soc-design-principle-in-redux-using-redux-saga-210516b51160)